# Open Source SharePoint Project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, solution-deployment, visual-studio-2012

Goal:
Learn real-based SharePoint project based on customization with Visual Studio. 
I wanna learn the source code, architecture, N-tier etc of a completed SP project.

Problem:
Is there one or many open source SP project that can be downloaded for free?

Information:
- I'm using SharePoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL server 2012

Comment: Just a side note here: you can search for any solutions on http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=sharepoint relating to sharepoint and view each project's source code and structure.

Answer (score 1):

On the Microsoft site for sharing code samples, located at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ I found 144 solutions tagged [**SharePoint Server 2013**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=sharepoint&f%5B1%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B1%5D.Value=SharePoint%20Server%202013&f%5B1%5D.Text=SharePoint%20Server%202013), which I belive will keep you occupied over the weekend :-)